# How to detect the disconnect of GraphQLWsLink?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I am using GraphQLWsLink to connect to my graphql server in react. However, sometimes the connection is down and after a few attempts apollo client does not attempt reconnecting.

Is there a way I could detect when the websocket connection is down? What would be the best way of forcing reconnecting?